# How would I use regex to parse this chord scheme?

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following input as an example:

```
[Ami]Song lyrics herp derp [F]song lyrics continue
[C7/B]Song lyrics continue on another [F#mi7/D]line
```

I need to parse the above and echo it as the following:

```
<div class="chord">Ami</div>Song lyrics herp derp <div class="chord">F</div>song lyrics continue
<div class="chord">C7/B</div>Song lyrics continue on another <div class="chord">F#mi7/D</div>line
```

So basically, I need to:

1) change `[` to `<div class="chord">`,

2) then append the content of the brackets,

3) then change `]` to `</div>`.

... using PHP 5.3+.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will work.

```
$tab = "[Ami]Song lyrics herp derp [F]song lyrics continue
[C7/B]Song lyrics continue on another [F#mi7/D]line";

echo str_replace(
    array('[', ']'),
    array('<div class="chord">','</div>'),
    $tab
);
```

Comment: That looks like a neat solution, wonder why I didn't think about that before. Is it faster/better than regex?

Comment: @RiMMER: They should both be linear-time but this solution will probably be faster because there is less overhead. As fun as regex's are they are not always the correct answer in practice :)

Comment: Well, this definitely looks like the best solution, but I'll wait for others to vote before I accept anything, I hope that's OK with everyone :)

Comment: view http://www.php-scripts.com/php_diary/011303.php3 - I think this way it'S easier to understand what you replace

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]/', '<div class="chord">\1</div>', $subject);

# \[(.*?)\]
# 
# Match the character “[” literally «\[»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
#    Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
#       Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
# Match the character “]” literally «\]»
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo preg_replace('#\\[([^]]*)\\]#','<div class="chord">$1</div>',$string);
```

Beware of html code or malformed `[]`s in your input string though,

Answer (score 0):

Pattern

```
 \[(.*?)\]
```

Replace with

```
<div class="chord">$1</div>
```

As will all regex uses, you want to be careful with bad [] pairs, and if the lyric could somehow contain [ then you will want to properly escape that.